# Firebase Document path must not be null Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I'm having a problem with nulls when going into this game activity. Here I leave you the code of the error and the methods with the lines of the crash. Maybe I'm missunderstanding something, sorry for my english.

Error code:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.venomapps.tictactoeonline, PID: 20007
java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:906)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.0:103)
    at com.venomapps.tictactoeonline.Activities.GameActivity.gameListener(GameActivity.java:136)
    at com.venomapps.tictactoeonline.Activities.GameActivity.onStart(GameActivity.java:131)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Method lines: 
`

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        gameListener();
    }

    private void gameListener(){
        listenerRegistration = database.collection("games")
                .document(gameId)
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if(e != null){
                            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, getString(R.string.try_again_later), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        assert documentSnapshot != null;
                        String source = documentSnapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites() ? "Local" : "Server";
                        if(documentSnapshot.exists() && source.equals("Server")){
                            // Parsing documentSnapshot to Game object.
                            game = documentSnapshot.toObject(Game.class);

                            if(player1Name.isEmpty() || player2Name.isEmpty()){
                                getPlayerNames();
                            }

                            updateUI();
                        }

                        updatePlayersUI();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not including enough information in your question to know exactly what's going on, but the error message is telling you that you can't pass null to `document()`.  That means the argument `gameId` is null. You're going to have to think carefully about what value you think it should have, and do some debugging to figure out why it's null instead.

Comment: I've solved it in some cases it was null because the other activity wasn't passing it at the right moment. Thanks you any way!